# Can't compile NDK android project

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk

I am using android studio and openning the hello-jni sample project.
However when I trying to compile the project,it prompts:

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: 

/Users/xx/opensource/android-sdk-macosx
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

I had installed the android 6.0 (api 23).Why still prompts failed to find?
I looked up in the preference in android stuido ,in android SDK tab it seems android 6.0 (api level 23 revision 1) can be found.

Belows is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.hellojni"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel      = 3
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
    }
    /*
     * native build settings
     */
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-jni"
        /*
         * Other ndk flags configurable here are
         * cppFlags += "-fno-rtti"
         * cppFlags += "-fno-exceptions"
         * ldLibs    = ["android", "log"]
         * stl       = "system"
         */
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles  += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi"
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86_64"
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips"
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips64"
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
}
```

[image: android sdk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

- I removed the application I was working on in home directory under   AndroidStudioProjects
- Restarted Android Studio
- It prompt the Android Studio Wizard, I went through the Android
  Studio Setup Wizard where it downloaded some SDK Build-tools for
  revision 23.0.1.
- I also clicked on update link when the "Platform and Plugin Updates" message show up while downloading Android SDK Build-tools, to update
  some components.
- "Welcome to Android Studio" in the Android Setup Wizard will show up,
  click on Configure, it will show the Android SDK Manager fetching
  some packages as shown in the previous answer, click on new or
  updates links
- Once the packages are done loading you can go ahead and Install the
  available packages. After installing the default selected packages
  you may get more that are selected. Install Android SDK License. You
  should select each one and then click on accept license. Android
  Studio will the go through a gradle build process

Comment: +1. I spent hours trying to fix it ... turns out, the projects carry Gradle files within them too! I copied my source code, deleted the entire project, created a new project, and pasted the old code. Gradle synced! Thanks for this simple solution ...

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered same problem and I think it is a bug. But I managed to make it work with the following workaround:

1. First be sure you both install the api and also build-tools (see figure below)
2. Than in build.gradle, change versions for api and build tools to previous ones: i.e.

   ```
       android{ compileSdkVersion = 22
       buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"    
       defaultConfig.with {
           applicationId = "com.sample.teapot"
           minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 11
           targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
       }
   ```

   }
3. Sync gradle successfully
4. Change versions back

I also restarted android studio several times but not sure whether it is required or not.

[image: Don't Forget to install Android SDK Build-tools]